# When I open parent Div i want to enlarge need to revert when I click again

Tags: javascript

When I open a `div` with a class "small" he gets a new class - "big". I want to click on "X" image and remove "big" class to make this `div` again "small". But when i am clicking on "X" nothing can happen because"X" is "small" class too i think...

Any ideas?

```js
const small = document.getElementsByClassName('small');
const information = document.getElementsByClassName('information');
const big = document.getElementsByClassName('big');
const zamknij = document.getElementsByClassName('zamknij');

for (let i = 0; i < small.length; i++) {
  small[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    small[i].classList.add("big");
    information[i].classList.add("widoczne");
    zamknij[i].style.display = "inherit ";
  });



}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #F9F9F9;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #7f8c8d;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.zamknij {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.zamknij:hover {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.4s;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.small {
  max-width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #3498db 50%, #2980b9 50%);
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: relative;
}

.small:hover {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #3498db 50%, #2980b9 50%);
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scale(1.07);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 13px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}

.medium {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #2ecc71 50%, #27ae60 50%);
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.medium:hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #2ecc71 50%, #27ae60 50%);
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scale(1.07);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 13px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}

.big {
  max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 1000px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #1abc9c 50%, #16a085 50%);
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: relative;
}

.big:hover {
  max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 1000px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #1abc9c 50%, #16a085 50%);
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: scale(1.07);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 13px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#lvl {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  width: 60px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.widoczne {
  visibility: visible;
}

.niewidoczne {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class=small>
    <div><img src="/ICONS/close.png" class="zamknij"></div>
    <img id="lvl" src="/ICONS/level-up.png">
    <h2>ROZBUDOWA</h2>
    <h3 class="information niewiodczne">
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis aut neque animi unde nostrum voluptatibus ipsa quos. Adipisci odit laborum quis sapiente tempore ullam placeat dolorum et accusamus voluptates? Exercitationem.
    </h3>
  </div>

  <div class=small>
    <div><img src="/ICONS/close.png" class="zamknij"></div>
    <h2>CENY</h2>
    <h3 class="information niewiodczne">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit repellat ratione maxime corrupti atque quos amet, tempora quisquam deleniti optio corporis exercitationem neque.</h3>
  </div>

  <div class=small>PROGRAMY NAPRAWCZE</div>
  <div class=small>Polecane dyski</div>
  <div class=small>ZAproponuj klientowi</div>
  <div class=small>częste usterki</div>
  <div class=small>Zwróć uwagę!</div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Koxer this is how you should have posted your question.  Let's see how fast we get an answer.  The issue isn't that complicated

Comment: you can use ```classList.toggle("big")``` instead of 'add' to remove 'big' class by click.

Comment: you are half right! what else do you have to do? (you should always test out your answers!)

Comment: yep, thank you DCR. he should toggle other added classes like "widoczne". or he can add another EventListener to close 'X' button and remove added clasess by click.

Comment: @Koxer are you getting all this?